# Databricks spark submit - getting error with --py-files

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

In Databricks workflows, I submit a spark job (Type = "Spark Submit"), and a bunch of parameters, starting with --py-files. The appl_src.zip contains application code and common functions.

```
"--py-files",
"s3://some_path/appl_src.zip",
"s3://some_path/main.py",
```

That works fine. But now I'd like to have three Python files, putting the "common" module in a different s3 path, like this:

```
"--py-files",
"s3://some_path/appl_src.py",
"s3://some_path/main.py",
"s3://a_different_path/common.py",
```

But then I get an error saying "common" doesn't exist, when I know in fact the path exists. In fact the log4j mentions the first two, but not the third:

```
24/02/28 21:41:00 INFO Utils: Fetching s3://some_path/appl_src.py to ...
24/02/28 21:41:00 INFO Utils: Fetching s3://some_path/main.py to ...
```

And then from Standard output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local_disk0/tmp/spark-123/appl_src.py", line 21, in <module>
    from common import my_functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

Does Spark only read the first two Python arguments?

Comment: Can you show the full command? What happens when you change the order of those files? The py-files should be one comma separated string I think. Maybe run it with `--py-files s3://some_path/appl_src.py,s3://some_path/main.py,s3://a_different_path/common.py`, or as in your case `"--py-files", "s3://some_path/appl_src.py,s3://some_path/main.py,s3://a_different_path/common.py"`

Comment: The whole thing looks like
["--py-files",

"s3://some_path/appl_src.zip",

"s3://some_path/main.py",

"--aws_secret_name","my_name",

"--aws_region_name","us-east-1",

"--sfurl","company.com",

"--sfdatabase","MY_DB",

etc.]

Comment: I tried your way but Databricks doesn't let me save it